# SQL Duplicate Rows Multiple Joins

Tags: sql, duplicates, left-join

I'm pretty much a noob when it comes to SQL so any help would be appreciated. I have a large data set that I am filtering through for a hospital. I am pulling data from 6 different tables and one of my tables has duplicate rows for each visit. I only want to pull in one row for each visit (it doesn't matter which row is pulled in). I know I need to use a DISTINCT, or GROUP BY clause but my syntax must be wrong.

```
    SELECT
         ADV.[VisitID]          AS  VisitID
        ,ADV.[Name]             AS  Name
        ,ADV.[UnitNumber]       AS  UnitNumber
        ,CONVERT(DATE,ADV.[BirthDateTime])                          AS  BirthDate
        ,ADV.[ReasonForVisit]   AS  ReasonForVisit
        ,ADV.[AccountNumber]    AS  AccountNumber
        ,DATEDIFF(day, ADV.ServiceDateTime, DIS.DischargeDateTime)  AS LOS
        ,ADV.[HomePhone]        AS  PhoneNumber
        ,ADV.[ServiceDateTime]  AS  ServiceDateTime
        ,ADV.[Status]           AS  'Status'
        ,PRV.[PrimaryCareID]    AS  PCP
        ,LAB.[TestMnemonic]     AS  Test
        ,LAB.[ResultRW]         AS  Result
        ,LAB.[AbnormalFlag]     AS  AbnormalFlag
        ,LAB.[ResultDateTime]   AS  ResultDateTime
        ,DIS.[Diagnosis]        AS  DischargeDiagnosis
        ,DIS.[ErDiagnosis]      AS  ERDiagnosis
        ,DCP.[TextLine]         AS  ProblemList


FROM          Visits                                      ADV
    LEFT JOIN Tests                                       LAB             ON ( LAB.VisitID  = ADV.VisitID AND
                                                                               LAB.SourceID = ADV.SourceID )
    LEFT JOIN Discharge                                   DIS             ON ( DIS.VisitID  = LAB.VisitID AND
                                                                               DIS.SourceID = LAB.SourceID )
    LEFT JOIN Providers                                   PRV             ON ( PRV.VisitID  = DIS.VisitID AND
                                                                               PRV.SourceID = DIS.SourceID )
    LEFT JOIN ProblemListVisits                           EPS             ON ( EPS.VisitID  = PRV.VisitID AND
                                                                               EPS.SourceID = PRV.SourceID )                                                                                                 
    LEFT JOIN ProblemList                                 DCP             ON ( DCP.PatientID = EPS.PatientID AND
                                                                               DCP.SourceID  = EPS.SourceID )


WHERE ( DCP.[TextLine]       LIKE '%Diabetes%'          OR 
        DCP.[TextLine]       LIKE '%Diabetic%'          OR
        DCP.[TextLine]       LIKE '%DM2%'               OR
        DCP.[TextLine]       LIKE '%DKA%'               OR
        DCP.[TextLine]       LIKE '%Hyperglycemia%'     OR
        DCP.[TextLine]       LIKE '%Hypoglycemia%'    ) AND
      ( LAB.[TestMnemonic] = 'GLU'                      OR
        LAB.[TestMnemonic] = '%HA1C'                  ) AND
        ADV.[Status]      != 'DIS CLI'                )
```

So this works okay, but when the doctor goes into the patient's Problem List and makes a change it refiles the whole list, which populates the ProblemList table again. So for 1 visit, I may get 4 duplicate entries thanks to the ProblemList and I only want one. It doesn't matter which one either.

I tried referencing other questions and nest another SELECT statement in but I just kept getting syntax errors.

This is what the duplicate values look like:

```
1111111111  SMITH,JOHN  1111    1/1/1901    CHEST PAIN  1111    2   111-111-1111    1/1/1901 12:15  DIS IN  DOEJO   GLU 120  H  1/2/1901 6:35   NULL    CHEST PAIN  Diabetes type 2, controlled
1111111111  SMITH,JOHN  1111    1/1/1901    CHEST PAIN  1111    2   111-111-1111    1/1/1901 12:15  DIS IN  DOEJO   GLU 120  H  1/2/1901 6:35   NULL    CHEST PAIN  Diabetes type 2, controlled
1111111111  SMITH,JOHN  1111    1/1/1901    CHEST PAIN  1111    2   111-111-1111    1/1/1901 12:15  DIS IN  DOEJO   GLU 120  H  1/2/1901 6:35   NULL    CHEST PAIN  Diabetes type 2, controlled
1111111111  SMITH,JOHN  1111    1/1/1901    CHEST PAIN  1111    2   111-111-1111    1/1/1901 12:15  DIS IN  DOEJO   GLU 120  H  1/2/1901 6:35   NULL    CHEST PAIN  Diabetes type 2, controlled
```

At the very end, the 'Diabetes type 2, controlled' is what's causing the duplicates. If I remove the ProblemListVisit and ProblemList tables from the query I get only one row of data.

What's most important is getting all of the unique Test results but NOT all the duplicate entries of the problem list (just want to know what type of diabetes they have, ONCE).

Thanks!

Comment: to get a distinct you should just put the word `distinct` next to your word `select` then run the query as is.  Still its better to find out why you have duplicates.  Presumably, there are values in the problemlistvisit and problemlist tables that you are not showing in your select list, but that are not distinct.  Better track those down by doing `select *` and figuring out the values that are causing "duplicates"

Comment: Before just throwing DISTINCT in there I would try to get to the bottom of the real problem. Selecting all the columns `SELECT *...` and finding the columns that are different among otherwise duplicated rows, would be a good troubleshooting step.

Comment: As @dan08 said, but I'm most interested in the nature of the duplication in the `ProblemList` table, as opposed to in the query results, as the former drives the latter.

Comment: Your joins look suspicious.  Almost everything is being joined via the same `VisitID` and `SourceID`, but it looks doubtful that all the tables are related in a way corresponding to the join.  Also, does the ProblemList table *not* have a `VisitID` column like all the other tables do?  If it has one, then you probably need to take that into consideration when you join that table.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I knew why there were duplicates. Unfortunately, every time the doctor filed the problem list it created a new entry which was attached to the same `PatientID`, thereby creating duplicates.
@John: The ProblemList table does not have a `VisitID`, that's correct. That's why I had to join ProblemListVisit table first, which has both `VisitID` and `PatientID`
@paqogomez: Didn't realize `Distinct` was that easy! Thanks, it worked just fine.

Comment: BTW: referring to `DCP` and `LAB` in the where clause will cause all your LEFT JOINS to act as plain joins. BTW2: the OR lists can be replaced by `IN(...)`, which will reduce the amount of parentheses. (and I *think* that `'%HA1C'` is a typo in a literal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lieu of `DISTINCT` which I think would be the quickest way of achieving this, you could also move each of your tables that generate multiple lines into a subquery wherein you GROUP BY the values that you seek for your JOINS and SELECTS.

There are two advantages here:

1. You gain more control over the output from these more granular tables and
2. you reduce the overhead on the JOIN, which will cut your I/O and CPU usage, when you restrict what they allow through with the WHERE clause inside the subquery.

Code:

```
SELECT
         ADV.[VisitID]          AS  VisitID
        ,ADV.[Name]             AS  Name
        ,ADV.[UnitNumber]       AS  UnitNumber
        ,CONVERT(DATE,ADV.[BirthDateTime])                          AS  BirthDate
        ,ADV.[ReasonForVisit]   AS  ReasonForVisit
        ,ADV.[AccountNumber]    AS  AccountNumber
        ,DATEDIFF(day, ADV.ServiceDateTime, DIS.DischargeDateTime)  AS LOS
        ,ADV.[HomePhone]        AS  PhoneNumber
        ,ADV.[ServiceDateTime]  AS  ServiceDateTime
        ,ADV.[Status]           AS  'Status'
        ,PRV.[PrimaryCareID]    AS  PCP
        ,LAB.[TestMnemonic]     AS  Test
        ,LAB.[ResultRW]         AS  Result
        ,LAB.[AbnormalFlag]     AS  AbnormalFlag
        ,LAB.[ResultDateTime]   AS  ResultDateTime
        ,DIS.[Diagnosis]        AS  DischargeDiagnosis
        ,DIS.[ErDiagnosis]      AS  ERDiagnosis
        ,DCP.[TextLine]         AS  ProblemList


FROM          Visits                                      ADV
    LEFT JOIN Tests                                       LAB             ON ( LAB.VisitID  = ADV.VisitID AND
                                                                               LAB.SourceID = ADV.SourceID )
    LEFT JOIN Discharge                                   DIS             ON ( DIS.VisitID  = LAB.VisitID AND
                                                                               DIS.SourceID = LAB.SourceID )
    LEFT JOIN Providers                                   PRV             ON ( PRV.VisitID  = DIS.VisitID AND
                                                                               PRV.SourceID = DIS.SourceID )
    LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 
                VisitID, 
                SourceID, 
                PatientID
            FROM ProblemListVisits 
            GROUP BY 
                VisitID, 
                SourceID, 
                PatientID
        )                                                 EPS             ON ( EPS.VisitID  = PRV.VisitID AND
                                                                               EPS.SourceID = PRV.SourceID )                                                                                                 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 
                PatientID, 
                SourceID, 
                TextLine 
            FROM ProblemList 
            WHERE 
                [TextLine]       LIKE '%Diabetes%'          OR 
                [TextLine]       LIKE '%Diabetic%'          OR
                [TextLine]       LIKE '%DM2%'               OR
                [TextLine]       LIKE '%DKA%'               OR
                [TextLine]       LIKE '%Hyperglycemia%'     OR
                [TextLine]       LIKE '%Hypoglycemia%' 
            GROUP BY 
                PatientID, 
                SourceID, 
                TextLine 
        )                                                  DCP             ON ( DCP.PatientID = EPS.PatientID AND
                                                                               DCP.SourceID  = EPS.SourceID )


WHERE ( LAB.[TestMnemonic] = 'GLU'                      OR
        LAB.[TestMnemonic] = '%HA1C'                  ) AND
        ADV.[Status]      != 'DIS CLI'                )
```

In the event that you are still getting multiples it suggests that [TextLine] has more than one value for each VisitID/PatientID combination in your ProblemList table. At that point you can remove that one from your GROUP BY clause and use some sort of aggregation on that field like `MAX([TextLine])` in your subquery. I suspect, though, that you won't have duplicates after using `DISTINCT` or using this subquery method.

Comment: Your code rocks man! Thanks so much. I'm putting this as the answer, because it ran a full 20 seconds faster than just using `Distinct`. The only catch, was that I was getting NULL values for the `[TextLine]` as well as the ones defined in the subquery's WHERE clause. 

So I just added:
    `WHERE DCP.[TextLine] IS NOT NULL   ) ` at the end of the main query after `ADV.[Status] != 'DIS CLI' ` and it worked like a charm.

Thanks for putting that together for me it helped a lot!

Comment: I was just reading through this answer and realized that I had left out the `AND DCP.[TextLine] IS NOT NULL` condition to replicate the same output from your original query. Sorry I missed that.

Comment: Forgot to mention too that I had to use the actual column names in the GROUP BY clause instead of numbers. So it was `GROUP BY [PatientID],[SourceID],[TextLine]` and same above. Also, note that there shouldn't be an extra `SourceID` in the first subquery. Thanks again for the code @JNevill

Answer (score 1):

the `Distinct` clause should do the trick 
but if not you can change

```
LEFT JOIN ProblemList   DCP             ON ( DCP.PatientID = EPS.PatientID AND
                                             DCP.SourceID  = EPS.SourceID )
```

for

```
OUTER APPLY (Select top 1 DCP.[TextLine]  FROM  ProblemList   DCP WHERE
                                             DCP.PatientID = EPS.PatientID  
                                           AND DCP.SourceID  = EPS.SourceID) DCP
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I had a query where simply adding a join, even without referencing anything in it, caused every single row to be straight duplicated.  This replacement cleared that right up.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `DISTINCT` after `SELECT`.  Something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     ADV.[VisitID]          AS  VisitID
    ,ADV.[Name]             AS  Name 
    ...
```